# Are there any simple ways of calling the "AD Object Picker" in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a Powershell 5.0 script with a form in which the user can optionally select an AD object.

Upon clicking a button, I need to present them with the "AD Object Picker" dialog (I'm not sure if that's what it's called), eg:

[image]

...and store their selected object in a variable.

I'm not sure how to properly call this dialog in Powershell as I don't even know what it's officially named (which makes researching it difficult), let alone if there's a .NET control or wrapper for it.

Can you show me a method to call up this dialog (and what the darned thing is actually called)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That dialog is built into Windows and is called the [`IDsObjectPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Objsel/nn-objsel-idsobjectpicker) interface. So whatever solution is used needs to be able to call native Windows code. This isn't easy from PowerShell. [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/AD/directory-object-picker) is in C++.

There is some discussion about using it from PowerShell [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0b03ac15-72bb-473f-884e-9e5144643b8d/powershell-guis-active-directory-directory-object-picker?forum=ITCG), with some example PowerShell code that may or may not work.

There is also a link to [this project](http://www.silogix.fr/developpement/outils/Ressources-PowerShell/Directory-Object-Picker-en-PowerShell.aspx) that has a wrapper DLL for all the native code that you can use from PowerShell (examples there too), but one of the comments said that it didn't work in newer PowerShell versions.

Answer (score 1):

This one seem to work, I tested in on 5.1 version

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Active-Directory-Object-a832f7bd

Comment: This ended up working perfectly for my application, but the other answer got to the core of the question so I felt inclined to mark it best. Thanks for posting this though! +1

Comment: It appears this link (and the project behind it) is dead, but seems to have been revived here: https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker

Answer (score 0):

There is now a PowerShell module in the gallery for that!

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ActiveDirectoryObjectPicker

https://github.com/realslacker/ActiveDirectoryObjectPicker